# EF Core: include only instance of many-nav property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

```
public class Chat 
{
    public string ChatID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message 
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
}
```

How can I load list of chats with included the latest (only) (ordered by `Message.Time`) message for `ICollection<Message> Messages` nav property per single request to DB? There is not Include with condition (chat.messages.last()) in EF Core

Comment: Which version are you using? there's a lot of issues opened about navigation properties and EF Core 2

Comment: @Fals v.1.1.1 `Include(c => c.Messages.Last())` throws `InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'c => {[c].Messages => Last()}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'`

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `Chats` that have no `Messages` as well? Or just chats that have at least one message (ordered by msg time)?

Comment: @Andrés Robinet in my scenario every chat has at least one message. I just want to retrieve list of chats with only message in their ICollection<Message> nav property

Answer (score 0):

This works in EF6, not sure in EF Core

You can follow [@CodeNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797882/codenotfound) idea, modify it slightly and ***maybe*** still get a single roundtrip to the database, provided that you are only interested in chats that have messages

```
var chatInfos = db.Chats
    .Where(chat => ...) // filter chats if you need to
    .SelectMany(chat =>

        // INNER JOIN with Messages, ORDER by Time, SELECT TOP 1
        chat.Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.Time).Take(1),

        // Explicitly load Chat, LastMessage and no more than that
        (chat, msg) => new
        {
            Chat = chat,
            LastMessage = msg
        })

     // Materialize!!
     // EF will fix-up Chat-Message navigation and will know that LastMessage is in the Chat's messages collection
    .ToList()

     // Sort again, you have the last message but not the chats ordered by last message 
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastMessage.Time)

    // Now you have a list of chats, with last message, sorted by last message time
    .ToList();

foreach (var info in chatInfos)
{
    var chatEntry = db.Entry(info.Chat);
    var messageCollection = chatEntry.Collection(x => x.Messages);

    // Tell EF that the collection is loaded
    // Though the last query only loaded ONE Message entity via Explicit Loading
    messageCollection.IsLoaded = true;
}

// Get the chats, now calls to chat.Messages should not be lazy loaded for these and the collection should contain only one Message
var chats = chatInfos.ConvertAll(x => x.Chat);
```

I didn't test **this code**, but have similar code working on EF 6